# Convergence/divergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx$?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Does the following converge or diverge:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$

I was thinking simply

$$\int_0^1 \bigg |\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx \bigg | \le \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$ and the latter converges.

It can't be this simple though?

Comment: *"It can't be this simple though?"*. Why not?

Comment: I think you can do this, but you can also use substitution and see it as an improper integral with infinity as one of its limits.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $\;u=\frac1x\;$ to get the improper integral

$$\int_\infty^1-\frac{du}{u^2}\,\sqrt u\,\sin u=\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin u}{u^{3/2}}du$$

and now use the comparison theorem to show absolute convergence:

$$\left|\frac{\sin u}{u^{3/2}}\right|\le\frac1{u^{3/2}}\implies\;\;\text{since}\;\;\int_1^\infty\frac{du}{u^{3/2}}=\left.-\frac2{\sqrt u}\right|_1^\infty=2\;\;\;\text{converges}$$

then so does our integral *absolutely*

Comment: How did you infer the bounds in the substitution?

Comment: @mavavilj As usual: $$x=0\implies u=\frac1x\xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{}\infty\;,\;\;x=1\implies u=\frac1x=\frac11=1\;$$